# WinForms: handles keyword disappears on custom DataGridViewColumn event

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

**Summary:** VB.NET has the `handles` clause for attaching event handlers.  When the event belongs to a custom `DataGridViewColumn`, the WinForms designer removes this clause from the code each time the "edit columns" dialog of the `DataGridView` is used.

**Long version:** I implemented a simple `DataGridViewColumn` by deriving from the `DataGridViewButtonColumn` class.  All it does is add an event `GetImage`, used by the paint logic of the cell (the cell code is not relevant to the problem).

```
Public Class DataGridViewAdvButtonColumn
    Inherits DataGridViewButtonColumn

    Public Sub New()
        Me.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewAdvButtonCell
    End Sub

    Public Event GetImage(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByRef image As Image)

    Friend Sub OnGetImage(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByRef image As Image)
        RaiseEvent GetImage(rowIndex, image)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function Clone() As Object
        Return TryCast(MyBase.Clone, DataGridViewAdvButtonColumn)
    End Function

End Class
```

Now suppose I use this column type on a specific form, and I attach a handler to the `GetImage` event, like so:

```
Private Sub column_GetImage(rowIndex As Integer, ByRef image As Image) Handles column.GetImage
    ' ...
End Sub
```

The problem I am experiencing is that the WinForms designer removes the `handles` clause whenever I open the "edit columns" dialog of the `DataGridView` hosting the column.  Result:

```
Private Sub column_GetImage(rowIndex As Integer, ByRef image As Image) 
    ' ...
End Sub
```

That should obviously not happen.  It is very dangerous, because it mostly goes unnoticed (produces no compiler errors).

I already tried adding code to the `Clone` method of the column, to copy over attached event handlers.  However, that did not change anything (I noted that there are no attached events at design time anyway).  I also tried changing the signature of the event to something more "conventional" with `e As GetImageEventArgs` instead of `ByRef image As Image`; didn't help.

This should be a common problem, but somehow nobody seems to be using custom events on their custom `DataGridViewColumns`.  So Google did not turn up anything either.

---

**Steps to reproduce:** To answer the questions of user Plutonix, here the detailed steps to reproduce this (compiles with option strict).

- Create a WinForms project.
- Add the `DataGridViewAdvButtonColumn` class (code above) to the project
- Add the `DataGridViewAdvButtonCell` class (code below) to the project
- Compile
- Use the designer to add a `DataGridView` to the `Form1.vb` form.
- Use the designer to add a new column of type `DataGridViewAdvButtonColumn` to the `DataGridView`
- Select the column in the property editor, click on the events icon (so that all events are listed) and double-click on the `GetImage` event.
- You are now in the code-behind of the form with an event handler as shown in my example above.
- Go back to the designer; add another column (type does not matter) to the `DataGridView`
- Go back to the code-behind.  You will see that the `handles` statement for the event handler added in the previous step is now gone.  QED

Here is the code of the DataGridViewAdvButtonCell:

```
Public Class DataGridViewAdvButtonCell
    Inherits DataGridViewButtonCell

    Public Overrides Function Clone() As Object
        Return TryCast(MyBase.Clone, DataGridViewButtonCell)
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub Paint(graphics As Graphics, clipBounds As Rectangle, cellBounds As Rectangle,
                                  rowIndex As Integer, cellState As DataGridViewElementStates, value As Object, formattedValue As Object,
                                  errorText As String, cellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle, advancedBorderStyle As DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle,
                                  paintParts As DataGridViewPaintParts)

        MyBase.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts)

        ' Fire GetImage event
        Dim image As Image = Nothing
        DirectCast(OwningColumn, DataGridViewAdvButtonColumn).OnGetImage(rowIndex, image)
        If image IsNot Nothing Then
            ' do something..
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `Me.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewAdvButtonCell` celltemplate is of Type DGVCell, while your new Type is a DGVColumn - this wont compile with Option Strict.  I cant see how your new event is chained/connected to the Cell painting event either.

Comment: Also, how that event handler got into the form, and the column into the DGV would be worth knowing.

Comment: @Plutonix: there is really nothing special required to reproduce this (also, it does compile with option strict).  I included a detailed list of steps in the question; I also included the code of the `DataGridViewAdvButtonCell`.

Comment: Note that no other Column type has events to be consumed by the form. Columns are a subcomponent entirely managed and consumed by the DGV.  When the *new* column collection is returned it has to be re-serialized which removes your handler clause.  If you add logic to the column for handling the image (perhaps with a number of Image properties it is to choose from) you may be able to get something like what you want to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't figure out why this is happening, you can at least avoid this issue by using Addhandler to add the handlers yourself in the code. I know it's less than ideal but if the designer doesn't work properly it may be the only way to guarantee you have your handlers working at runtime.

```
AddHandler column.GetImage, Addressof column_GetImage
```

Comment: Sure, but that's not satisfactory, especially if the component in question is to be used by someone else.

Comment: Seems like a bug with datagridview edit - You can use the "add columns" menu item fine but any change in edit seems to rebuild the columns, losing the handler attached in this way. If you avoid the designer again (I know, not ideal), handlers you attach to subs yourself by typing "handles column1.GetImage" will stay attached